# how do I add Google Play services for my Android app without using Eclipse

Tags: android, push-notification, google-play-services, cordova-plugins

I'm trying to set up push notifications for Android phones and following the instructions here:
https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-0/notifications/push-notifications-hybrid-applications/

But the instructions for "Add Google Play Services" assume that I'm using Eclipse, which I'm not.
(Although I am using the ant builder, not gradle.)

How can I add `$android_sdk_location\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib` to my project without using Eclipse (and ideally, without using Android Studio)?

Should I (can I!) just use the Cordova plugin instead?
http://plugreg.com/plugin/MobileChromeApps/google-play-services

Comment: This is not related to MobileFirst, but to any Android project; removing tags.

Comment: @IdanAdar - so the docs for MFP give instructions only for Eclipse ... that's all the instruction IBM wants to give on their Frankensteined Cordova version?
:-)

Seriously, then are there docs on using Cordova plugins with an MFP project?

Comment: Actually going forward the Google Play Services instructions are removed and you are directed to Google's documentation, as it cannot be contained (Google updates it frequently), thus you should follow Google's docs.

Comment: OK, so that's good to know (so the "other" tab [here](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup) is what I'm looking for).

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Cordova plug-in, but I believe that **Google** (this is not related to MobileFirst at all, but to any Android project) assumes you are using either Eclipse or Android Studio or any other instructions - provided by Google...

As mentioned in the comments, such as these: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup